# HTML automatically refresh page but check for connection prior

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a Python based flask web application which shows some SQL information on a html page.

This page is semi-realtime, it gets refreshed every 15 minutes with a simple html refresh:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="9000">
```

This works fine as long as the connection is up, there are no internal code errors.

Now I don`t want to have to manually refresh the page once it cannot refresh the page correctly for whatever reason. (connection, internal error).

Is it possible to have a webpage that keeps refreshing every fixed period of time regardless on whether the last refresh was succesfull.

Currently the html page contains no Javascript or the like, just plain html which is generated by Flask built-in template engine Jinja2.

Is it maybe possible to load the webpage completely first than check if it was successful and then refresh?

Comment: jep; use the so called Ajax technology, to automatically load/reload page components/data. (Jquery is a good framework for this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the a javascript library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can do this with the asynchronous [Ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Here is an example of how you can replace your `<body>` content every 15 minutes if it is successfully loaded:

```js
function update_site() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/my/page/url/",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            // Replace body with loaded site. You can do more checks here to check
            // if the fetched content is all there.
            var body_html = /^.*<body>(.*)<\/body>.*$/g.exec(data)[1];
            $('body').html(body_html);
        }, 
        error: function(data) {
            // Couldn't load site. 
        }
    });
}
// Run every 15 minutes.
window.setInterval(function() {
  update_site();
}, 15*60*1000);
```

Comment: thanks this seems to work. I can see that I recieve a request on the server but the page doesn`t update. I think this might be a cashing problem?

Comment: no change sadly shouldn`t it be `.find('<body>')`? If you have the time you could check it out via teamviewer?

Comment: Nope, it's `('body')`. Try debugging with `alert(data)` and `$('body').html('test');`.

Comment: thx! My page is too large to show in the `alert()` prompt so I installed firebug real quick to check the data object. and it does correctly load the page as the data is updated in the data object. the Browser however doesn`t update it. `replacing$('body').html('test');` does work.

Comment: Then it should work. Maybe want you want to be updated is outside the body tag?

Comment: 100% sure it`s within the body tag, I do have a css file embedded in the html which contains settings for the body.

Comment: Maybe you should try to replace a smaller fraction of the page, for example a table that changes. You can select element IDs with $('#myid')

Comment: `body_html` is undefined. logging data show the entire page but after processing to `body_html` it is undefined...

Comment: it seems the problem was that jquery strips the <body> tags with `$()` using regex fixes it...             `var body_html = data.replace(/^[\S\s]*<body[^>]*?>/i, "")
                    .replace(/<\/body[\S\s]*$/i, "");`

Comment: Great, I've updated my answer to include regex instead.

Comment: Just a note: your interval is currently set to run every 15 _seconds_ not minutes.

Comment: Now it's set to run every 15,000 seconds (or approximately every 4 hours). You want `900000` milliseconds (as in `15 * 60 * 1000`).

Answer (score 0):

You could implement some javascript to check the connection when a button is pressed. You could use the navigator.onLine property which should work with all major browsers.

Read more here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_online.asp

Answer (score -2):

should try this

```js
function update_site() {
    $.ajax(
    {
    url: "/my/page/url/",
    dataType: "html",
    cache: false,
        success: function(event) 
        {
            var update_html = /^.*<body>(.*)<\/body>.*$/g.exec(event)[1];
            $('body').html(update_html);
        }, 
        error: function(event) {
            
        }
    });
}
// Run every 10 minutes.
window.setInterval(function() {
  update_site();
        // To refresh site every 15 min
}, 15000000);
```